# How can you retrieve pthread_key_t from pthread ID?

Tags: c++, pthreads

I'm trying to implement an easy way to store and retrieve thread local variables in C++ using pthreads.  Something similar to ThreadLocal in Java. I get the part where I create the pthread_key_t when I create the thread but how can I get that value from any place in my thread's code?  I can use pthread_self to get my thread ID but is it possible to get the TLS key once I have this?

P.S.: I know Boost does this but I'm not using Boost

Answer (score 1):

You generally don't create the `pthread_key_t` when you create the thread, you create it  once sometime before that and save the key id somewhere.

Once that's done, each thread has its own value for the contents of the key, and you can set and get the contents using `pthread_setspecific()` and `pthread_getspecific()` respectively.

Comment: Are you saying that calling pthread_key_create before you create each thread and then pass that value to the thread?  Then, once created, the thread can squirrel that value away along with it's thread ID.  After that, it's a matter of getting the thread ID and finding the key?

Comment: No, you call it _once_, not once per thread. You don't need to do anything with the thread ID either. Just have the `pthread_key_t` accessible to all threads. The get/setspecific functions can be used with the same key in any thread, providing a distinct value in each thread (and NULL if nothing was set yet).

Answer (score 0):

Use `pthread_getspecific` to return the value currently bound to the specified key on behalf of the calling thread and `pthread_setspecific` to associate a thread-specific value with a key obtained via a previous call to `pthread_key_create`.